# Sphinx How to edit heading layout in latex

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

I'd like to modify headings in generated latex pdf.
Briefly speaking I'd like to make level-1 heading look like "paragraph" heading.
This should be of form

```
<number>. Some Text
```

I found something in sphinxstylelatexheadings.sty but I'm not a latex expert and I don't know how to edit this.